# How to stop Twilio Voice API from expanding abbreviations in voice messages?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I have recently upgraded the Twilio library from version 3 to 5 on a project I am working on, and after finishing the upgrade I noticed that the voice messaging system is expanding abbreviations (for example, "assoc" gets read out as "association").  It is also expanding the word "tech" to "technical", even though that is not what "tech" stands for in context.

Is there a way to make Twilio read messages out verbatim, specifically without expanding things it thinks are abbreviations?  I have pored over the API docs and cannot find a setting to alter this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with voice `man` or `woman` not `alice`. For example:

This will expand to "association".
`<Say voice="alice">He works for an assoc in town.</Say>`

This will keep to "assoc".
`<Say voice="woman">He works for an assoc in town.</Say>`
`<Say voice="man">He works for an assoc in town.</Say>`

Another option would be to switch specific words for their phonetic spellings.

This will keep to "assoc" even with voice `alice`.
`<Say voice="alice">He works for an assok in town.</Say>`

There is a blog about this:
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/08/the-pronunciation-challenge.html